# Order of convergence of midpoint rule

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, matlab, numerical-calculus

A problem asks to integrate the function $f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x^4}$ on $[-1, 2]$ using the Midpoint rule and the Trapezoidal rule, which I did in MATLAB. Then it asks to determine the value of this integral exactly up to 10 decimal places, after which it asks to do a log-log plot of the absolute value of the truncation error of each method as a function of $h$ (the step size) and explain how to spot the order of convergence of each method from the plot. I attempted to do all this with the Midpoint rule, and hence come my questions:

- For the Midpoint rule, the error term is $\frac{h^3}{24} f''(c)$, with $c\in [-1,2]$. So I took the 3rd derivative of $f$, set it to $0$ and found the real roots of the function. I found that the greatest value of $f''$, in absolute value, which is $8$, is attained at $c=0$. So I set the error term function to be $g(h)=\frac13 h^3$. *Is this correct?*
- In MATLAB, I chose the range for $h$ as follows

> ```
> h = logspace(0.001,0.1);
> y = 1/3 * h.^3;
> loglog(h,y,'-s')
> grid on
> ```

which gave the following [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVtvV.png)

From which we can see that the ordinates axis increases at about the same rate as the abscissa axis. So the order of convergence must be linear. *Is this correct?*

- Lastly, I wasn't able to get the value of the integral to 10 decimal places even with $N=9600\cdot8$ ($h=3.9063 \times 10^{-5}$) with the Trapezoidal method. I'm reluctant to increase $N$ because MATLAB already takes about 10 minutes to do this, and my computer is very fast. *What is it that I'm doing wrong?* Why is MATLAB so slow in this case? I estimated it would need to do no more than 1,000,000 operations to perform this approximation.

Comment: Notice that since this is an odd function, the integral from $-1$ to $1$ is $0$. So you should just find the integral on the interval $[1,2]$. That should cut down the computation time.

Comment: This shortens the computation time, yet it looks like $N=72600$ is still not enough for the 10-digit precision. I'm wondering how come the computation process takes MATLAB several minutes to complete. It doesn't look like many billion operations are needed.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part IMO you misunderstood the task. I believe you were asked to compute the exact value by solving the integral,
$$
\int_{-1}^2\frac{x}{1+x^4}dx=\frac12\int_{1}^2\frac{d(x^2)}{1+(x^2)^2}dx=\frac12(\arctan(4)-\arctan(1))≈0.270\,209\,750\,135\,292
$$

Using that value as reference you get the errors of the methods as

[image: error plot]

where due to the accumulation of floating point noise there is an additional $\mu/h$ resp. $\mu N$ error term and the error is minimal where the method error $\sim N^{-2}$ is in balance with it, that is, $N\sim \sqrt[3]{1/\mu}$, which is with $\mu=10^{-16}$ at a scale of $10^5$.